# Inserting item (using boto3) into a dynamodb table ( db table created using CDK)

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, aws-cdk

I have a dynamodb table configured using CDK (i used python)in one script which is created using cdkstack. Now , I have another .py script which helps me insert data into the db table created using cdk.
My boto3 script is a minimal script which looks like this -

```
import boto3
ddb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = ddb.Table(db_stream_table.table_arn)
table.put_item(Item={'timestamp': "123456", 'current_status': "response received", "responded_with": "Yes",'ticket_id': 100})
```

I am not able to figure out how i can reference the dynamodb table created using cdk here in this boto3 script because the line `db_stream_table.table_arn` returns a token and that infact does not refer to the name of the table.
Also the name of the table looks somewhat like this: `InfratestcdkStack-TableCD557FA0-1S1M37VCP51C9`. (This table name is not as exactly depicted here , i have made a few changes to the numbers and alphabets, but it's the same format)

Am I missing something? or is my approach wrong? is there a simple way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are more easier approaches to this , but I figured out a solution which is to set ssm parameters in your cdk script like:

```
aws_ssm.StringParameter(self, "SsmParameterforDynamoDB",
        allowed_pattern=".*",
        description="The name of the DynamoDB table",
        parameter_name="dbname",
        string_value=db_stream_table.table_name, # this is the name of your db table as referenced in your cdk code
        tier=aws_ssm.ParameterTier.ADVANCED
        )
```

and then if you have a seperate script running boto to put an item into this table , you can have

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('ssm')

response = client.get_parameter(
    Name='dbname',
    WithDecryption=False
)
tbl_Transaction_table_name = response['Parameter']['Value']
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table(tbl_Transaction_table_name)
table.put_item(Item={'timestamp': "123456", 'current_status': "response received", "responded_with": "Yes",
                     'ticket_id': 100})
```

Maybe I'd try having an iam role to restrict access to this as an additional step.